# Postgres permissions to create objects, comparable to SQL Server

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with a test user who can do anything on a specific db, but is confinated:

-- The User creation

```
CREATE ROLE test LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '123465'
NOINHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEUSER NOREPLICATION
VALID UNTIL 'infinity';

--- His DB

grant connect on testdb to test;

-- Revokes to other dbs

revoke connect on <database> from <username>;
...
revoke connect on <database> from <username>;
revoke connect on <database> from public;
```

Is this correct? is this equivalent to `db_owner` in SQL Server? I'm forgetting something?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something: why can't you just make that user the owner of the database? `create database ... owner = the_user` or `alter database ... owner to some_user`

Comment: yes, is good, i trying to get a full permission user for each db. But the owner can be anyuser? not need special pemisions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's considered more useful to provide an answer rather than just links, but I can't see how anyone will explain more thoroughly than the manuals.

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/user-manag.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createrole.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createdatabase.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-grant.html

Comment: yes, of course, but the problem is the comparative for de 2nd question.

Comment: You'll need to help us a bit. Having read the above, what did you find confusing about PostgreSQL's concept of a database owner?

Comment: I'm newbie on postgres but i have a lot experience on sql server. This is my problme :P
I need to create a user that can do the same things that a db_owner in SQL Server. 
I try with superuser but is too much. I'm working creating a roll copying and apply the grants. The question is about if exists an easy way.

Comment: I'll repeat my question: Which part of the PostgreSQL documentation about database owner's caused the problem? Did none of the pages mention "owner"?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your patience Richard, i redefine the question after reading your previous links.